# Javascript - Access to object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data object in Javascript with all the data I need to show (I get the data from API).

I cannot understand why I cant access its properties. This is my data (from console.log):

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
distancia: "2.69"
id_servicio: "1"
latitud: "42.2261474"
longitud: "-8.7604453"
service_data: Array[1]

1: Object
distancia: "0.65"
id_servicio: "2"
latitud: "42.2272562"
longitud: "-8.7340278"
service_data: Array[1]

2: Object
distancia: "2.36"
id_servicio: "3"
latitud: "42.2338588"
longitud: "-8.7030846"
service_data: Array[1]

3: Object
distancia: "4.42"
id_servicio: "4"
latitud: "42.2154313"
longitud: "-8.6754155"
service_data: Array[1]
```

Now I have a loop for accesing the properties but It throws an error. I have checked every combination, but nothing works:

```
for ( i = 0; i<=datos.length; i++ ) {
      var servicio = datos[i];
      var nLatitud = servicio.latitud;
      var nLongitud = servicio.longitud;
      console.log(servicio);
      var auxll = new google.maps.LatLng(nLatitud,nLongitud);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
      });
      marker.setMap($scope.map);
    }
```

And thats the error I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitud' of undefined
    at generarMapa (myDashboardController.js:134)
    at myDashboardController.js:94
    at ionic.bundle.js:18899
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:23394)
    at ionic.bundle.js:23410
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24673)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24484)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24778)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:19191)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19363)
```

Comment: Classic off-by-one error...

Comment: Well, sometimes the error description confuses your mind, sorry for the confusion :_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `for` statements. Its accessing outside out the array by `<=`

```
for ( i = 0; i<=datos.length; i++ ) {
```

to

```
for ( var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++ ) {
```

Comment: I am simply an idiot. Oh god, the Ionic Framework error are not precisely accurate... I was focusing on the access to the object. God, thanks a lot!!!